# Chef: passing variables

Tags: linux, bash, chef-infra

Everytime we create a new server I have a bash script that asks the end-user a set of questions to help chef configure the custom server, his/her answer to those questions needs to be injected into chef so that I can use their responses within my chef script (to set the server "hostname" = "server1.stack.com", for instance). There is a json attribute when running chef-client I've read about that may be helpful but I'm not sure how that would work in our environment.

Note:  We run chef-client on all of our systems every 15 minutes via cronjob to get updates.

Psuedocode:

```
echo -n "What is the server name?"
read hostname

chef-client -j {'hostname' => ENV['$hostname']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues, first is that `-j` takes a filename not raw JSON and second is that using `-j` will entirely override the node data coming from the server which also includes the run list and environment. If this is being done at system provisioning time you can definitely do stuff like this, see [my AMI bootstrap script](https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/packer/client-bootstrap.sh#L31-L40) for an example. If this is done after initial provisioning, you are probably best off writing those responses to a file, and then reading that in from you Chef recipe code.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken.  I just verified on my server that passing in an argument to -j does not override the run_list or the environment.
In fact, if I am reading the source correctly, it does a deep merge between the -j contents and the normal attributes from the server.
https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/cbb9ae97e2d3d90b28764fbb23cb8eab4dda4ec8/lib/chef/node.rb#L293

Comment: I get the logic within the script, it looks like you are you running this client-bootstrap.sh on the target machine itself?

Answer (score 1):

Passing raw json into chef-client is possible, but requires a little creativity.  You simply do something like this:

```
echo '{"hostname": "$hostname"}' | chef-client -j /dev/stdin
```

The values in your json will be deep merged with the "normal" attributes stored in the chef-server. You can also include a run_list in your json, which will replace (not be merged) the run_list on the chef server.

You can see the run_list replacing the server run list here:
https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/cbb9ae97e2d3d90b28764fbb23cb8eab4dda4ec8/lib/chef/node.rb#L327-L338

And you can see the deep merge of attributes here:
https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/cbb9ae97e2d3d90b28764fbb23cb8eab4dda4ec8/lib/chef/node.rb#L305-L311

Also, any attributes you declare in your json will override the attributes already stored on the chef-server.

Comment: @coderanger would you mind taking a look at this for me?  I readily admit that you have way more experience in this domain than I do, and if I'm reading the source wrong I am happy to be corrected and remove my answer.